# How to read txt file from Google Drive?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make launcher for my game. I want it to display update log. How I want it to work:

Replace log.txt file on Google Drive and new log will be displayed in launcher.

I have no idea how to make this. Also I have to make auto-updater.

It will work similiar to update log - upload .jar file and res folder on drive. When game launched it will check for updates and if new update available it will download it.

Like I said, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you to use GitHub to upload your files. Then you can use the URL provided by GitHub to open a `urlStream` in your project and read that file like a `.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive is a file explorer only. It will allow you to upload and download files, it does not have the power to display or edit them.  Unless you want to display them in the Google drive web application in which case there should be a webContentLink available in the [response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels#Label) data for the [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method, however the file will need to be either public or the user must have access to it in order to be able to see it.

To display the file you will need to download it and display it locally.  To edit it you will need to download the file and edit it then upload it again.

Tbh i think what you are asking is out of scope for this api.

Comment: Okay, so I want program to download file to res folder. How?

Comment: The documentation contains information on how download works: [manage downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: Nontheless, you COULD download a file directly from GDrive. But that is so much hassle, going through all the necessary libraries, the OAuth(entication), the decoding... and in the end, Google stuff is quite volatile, with some APIs changing every few years. I sincerely regret using a lot of Google products for my applications, because it is a lot of long-term maintenance. As @roberto falcone suggests, GitHub is a lot easier so use and a lot more stable.